# Problems with fglrx driver installation

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

I have problems with fglrx installation.
Firs my ubuntu worked in my laptop with ati5145.
After motherboard of my laptop died i extracted HDD and placed it in my Desktop.
Old ati driver was deleted with:

```
/usr/share/ati/unistall-fglrx.sh
```

This script deleted also executable for X11 so i reinstalled it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-common
```

So i was able to work with my old ubuntu and integrated Intel HD graphics.
Now i have new Radeon R7 250 and try to install fglrx.
I tried to install driver from amd-website(package-generation works without problems) and with help of jockey-gtk.
Both *.deb installation processes fails.
It is error after driver install fails:

```
 update-alternatives: warning: force re-alternatives /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf, since the group of links i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf broken.
```

When this happens i use only open-source gallium0.4 driver.

```
dpkg-reconfigure fglrx
```

Returns that package is either broken or not installed correctly.

How can i fix this without ubuntu re-install?
Intel HD graphics is disabled in BIOS.
I need non-opensource driver for OpenCL.

- OS Ubuntu 12.04x64
- AMD R7 250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

Here is Step-by-step instruction.

№1
Reinstall mesa.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
```

№2
Restore alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --auto gl_conf
```

№3
Steps №1 and №2 solved problem with:

```
update-alternatives: warning: force re-alternatives /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf,
```

But when I tried to install fglrx driver, I got message than installer cannot create file in /etc/X11/Xsession.d. I checked /etc/X11 but there was no Xsession.d folder:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/Xsession.d
```

№4
Install fglrx from generated packages and reboot.